# Calling Protected Function From Another Contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I am trying to call a function in another contract, that is protected with an `openzepellin Role library`.

I am calling `availableFunction` on the javascript side, which in turn calls `protectedFunction`. Even though I pass the `adminRole` address to the constructor of contract `B`, and then call `availableFunction` with `adminRole`, the function reverts.

In `A.sol`

```
contract interfaceB {
  function protectedFunc() public;
}

contract A {
  B b;

  constructor(address _B) {
    b = new interfaceB(_B);
  }

  function availableFunction() {
    b.protectedFunc();
  }
}
```

In `B.sol`

```
contract B {
  using Roles for Roles.Role;
  Roles.Role private adminRole;

  constructor(address _adminRole) public {
    adminRole.add(_adminRole);
  }

  function protectedFunc() public {
    require(adminRole.has(msg.sender), "DOES_NOT_HAVE_ADMIN_ROLE");
    ...
  }

}
```

In `A.test.js`

```
const A = artifacts.require("A");
const B = artifacts.require("B");

contract("A", function ([_, adminRole]) {
  beforeEach(async function () {
    b = B.new(adminRole);
    a = A.new(b.address);

  }
  describe("availableFunc", function () {
    it("should pass!", async function () {
      a.availableFunc({from: adminRole)}); // REVERTS!
    })
  }
})
```

`Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert DOES_NOT_HAVE_ADMIN_ROLE`

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure your test calling `b.protectedFunc(..)` passes and if you call `a.availableFunction()` it will fail. When `protectedFunc` is called from `A` then `msg.sender` will be the address of `A`.

To make it work you have to use A address in the admin role.

```
const A = artifacts.require("A");
const B = artifacts.require("B");

contract("A", function ([_, adminRole]) {
  beforeEach(async function () {
    a = await A.new();
    b = await B.new(a.address);
  }
  describe("protectedFunc", function () {
    it("should pass!", async function () {
      a.availableFunction({from: adminRole)});
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks about right. I've changed my answer please, as there is an extra layer of complication that I missed - namely the constructor of `contract A ` needs `B.address`! Is there any solution in this case please?

Comment: You have a circular dependency A needs B address and B needs A address. You have to split creation in two steps for example 1) contract creation, 2) initialize admin rol.